# Java Ascii Values

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the ascii values of a string, print the next character following, and also print the preceding character. So if the user enters `b c d` I want my program to print out `98 99 100`, also `c d e` and lastly `a b c`. It's 3:30am and my brain is a little fried from trying to get these working. Here is what I have:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputValues3;

// User enters 3 character values here
System.out.println("Enter 3 character values");
inputValues3= input.readLine();
String[] charValues = inputValues3.split("\\s+");

System.out.println(inputValues3);    // prints out user character values
System.out.println();                // needs to print out ascii values
System.out.println();                // needs to print out following value
System.out.println();                // needs to print out preceding value
```

I have tried several different ways trying to make the characters to an integer value but have gotten several different errors depending on how I try to make it work.

Comment: To print out Ascii value, just convert `char` to `int` and print it

Comment: so convert string to char then char to int?

Comment: *"It's 3:30am and my brain is a little fried from trying to get these working."*  - Well go to bed.  You can't learn to program as 3:30am.

Comment: @Marcus Burkhart: itterate String to get characters, print out each character, convert it to int and print out given ascii code as well

Comment: This is a homework question, right?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
inputValues3= input.readLine();
for (char ch : inputValues3.toCharArray()) { 
    System.out.println((int) ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that:

```
for (int i = 0, n = inputValues3.length(); i < n; ++i) {
  char c = inputValues3.charAt(i);
  if (!Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
    System.out.print((int)c);
  }
}
System.out.println();
```

Eg: you iterate over the character contained in the String, and you skip the space (using `Character.isSpaceChar`). The cast is needed otherwise `System.out.print` will print the char and not its value.